# sending php and js variables through ajax to php page and mysql table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have been looking to some similar questions, but none seem to provide the specific answer I am looking for. I have a few js variables, which are being passed through ajax to a `location.php`, which will then put them in a mysql table. So far the ajax call looks like this:

```js
function postLocation()
{
  //var teamName = $('.team_name').val(); //Neither of the two work
 var teamName = document.getElementById('team_name').value;
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) 
  {
    pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
    $.ajax(
    {
      url:'location.php',
      type: 'POST',
      datatype: 'json',
      data: {
        'posx':position.coords.latitude, 
        'posy': position.coords.longitude, 
        'team_name':$team_name
      },   // post to location.php
      success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
      },

      error: function(data) {
        alert("There may an error on uploading. Try again later"); //This is what displays on the screen every time
      },
    });
  });    
}
```

You'll notice as well that I have `'team_name' = $team_name` -> this is essentially what I want to do, but I cannot find the best way to do this using my existing ajax structure.

**EDIT** using `var teamName = document.getElementById('team_name').value;` to get the value from a hidden field just causes the alert to give the error message. In the browser debug it tells me it's a 500 internal server error.

**EDIT 2** Here is my html code on the index.php page:

```html
<div class="titleText"><h1><?php 
 echo $stagerow['stage'];
 echo $id;
 $team_name = $_SESSION['team_name']; 
 echo $team_name;
 ?></h1>
 You can <a href="http://testphp-olivlaytchev.rhcloud.com/logout.php" style="color:white">logout here.</a> <br></div>
  <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </head>

  <input type ="hidden" id="team_name" name="team_name" value="<?php echo $team_name?>" >
  <!-- Script -->
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script>
```

And this is the error message I get from the browser `POST http://testphp-olivlaytchev.rhcloud.com/location.php 500 (Internal Server Error)send 
@ jquery.js:9664m.extend.ajax 
@ jquery.js:9215(anonymous function) 
@ (index):259`

line 259 is `$.ajax(`

Comment: Where does $team_name come from? Is it a php variable? Is it global JS variable? What is its scope?

Comment: From where you get varaible $team_name?

Comment: `'team_name':'<?PHP echo $team_name; ?>'`

Comment: team_name is a '$_SESSION' variable

Comment: @mplungjan that doesn't work - tried it already

Comment: If the JS is inline then `'team_name':'<?PHP echo $_SESSION["team_name"]; ?>'` should work. If it is an external JS, you need to add it to the PHP page

Comment: well it's inline and putting in the echo does not work - the page does not load properly.

Comment: woops sec ill try with $_SESSION["team_name"]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if $team_name is a php variable, you can echo it out into a hidden input and grab its  val via js

```
<input type ="hidden" class="team_name" name="team_name" value="<?php echo $team_name?>" >
```

You have an error at the section when you pass data in your ajax.   `'team_name':$team_name` should be team_name: teamName`.

The first arg is passed to HTTP_POST as key index, the second is the value and  you don't need $ sign.

```
var teamName = $('.team_name').val();
data: {
    'posx':position.coords.latitude, 
    'posy': position.coords.longitude, 
     team_name: teamName 
  },   /
```

in your php you can access it like below.

```
echo $_POST['data'];
```

Comment: or directly into the script if it is inline

Comment: it must be failing, because I am getting the error message in the case of `error: function(data)`

Comment: @Oliver  add html, update your code and show full error message please. If will help answer your question and find errors quickly and accurately.

Comment: `var teamName = $('.team_name').val()` you are trying to get the val by class, your input does not have an attr class defined add `class="team_name"`. inspect element and check the value echoed out? what do you see?

Comment: if I use `var teamName = $('.team_name').val()` and output the value of teamName - it works correctly and has the correct teamname, however the issue must be in the data stream??

Comment: updated my answer, and explained why where the error is.